# Executing PowerShell Commands in Java Program

Tags: java, powershell

I have a `PowerShell Command` which I need to execute using `Java` program. Can somebody guide me how to do this?

My command is `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | 
Format-Table –AutoSize`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute Powershell script using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467676/execute-powershell-script-using-java)

Comment: Yes,I have gone through that question but can you give me a basic examle to set me going? I want to learn this.

Comment: You need to exercise your google-fu and look up some examples. There's no reason you can't at least make an attempt at researching this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should write a java program like this, here is a sample based on Nirman's Tech Blog, the basic idea is to execute the command calling the PowerShell process like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PowerShellCommand {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  //String command = "powershell.exe  your command";
  //Getting the version
  String command = "powershell.exe  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion";
  // Executing the command
  Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  // Getting the results
  powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
  String line;
  System.out.println("Standard Output:");
  BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
  while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
  }
  stdout.close();
  System.out.println("Standard Error:");
  BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
  while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
  }
  stderr.close();
  System.out.println("Done");

 }

}
```

In order to execute a powershell script

```
String command = "powershell.exe  \"C:\\Pathtofile\\script.ps\" ";
```

Comment: In case the path to the/a `.ps1` file contains a space, you can modify the `command` to: ```String command1 = "powershell.exe & 'C:/test folder with spaces/yourPowershellScript.ps1' ";``` to run the script from eclipse.

Comment: Just incase someone would like to execute multiple commands at one time, use `-and` or `-or` between your commands to connect them.

Answer (score 24):

No need of reinvent the wheel. Now you can just use [jPowerShell](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell). (Disclosure: I am the author of this tool.)

```
String command = "Get-ItemProperty " +
                "HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* " +
                "| Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate " +
                "| Format-Table –AutoSize";

System.out.println(PowerShell.executeSingleCommand(command).getCommandOutput());
```

Comment: I found your JAR to be not that robust, check my question + answer ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065666/executing-ads-related-powershell-command-through-java-does-not-work-giving-2-dif

Comment: Hello, for what I understand your problem was basically in the command string you sent to jPowershell and not in the JAR itself.

Comment: Just came across this post and comment.  I tried jPowerShell and got a couple simple examples working so just wanted to give my anecdotal endorsement of solution.  Thanks @profesor_falken

Comment: Is there anyway to use this library to execute commands which require admin privileges such as Disable-PnpDevice and Enable-PnpDevice?

Answer (score 5):

you can try to calle the powershell.exe with some commands like :

```
String[] commandList = {"powershell.exe", "-Command", "dir"};  

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);  

        Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: just a code sniped out of an old projekt you usualy dont need it

Answer (score -3):

You can use -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned in the command.

> String cmd = "cmd /c powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -noprofile -noninteractive C:\Users\File.ps1