# Pass parameter from array to powershell java program

Tags: java, arrays, powershell

I have a java code that execute a powershell script.My parameters are in a string array that I got from user.

```
String sentence = clientinp.readUTF();
            String[] parts = sentence.split(",");
```

How should I put the parameters to the script every time I execute the code?
I tried this code:

```
String command = "powershell.exe  $Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -ZoneName -Name -IPv4Address -TimeToLive";
```

But I don't know how can I pass this array to powershell.What should I do?

Comment: If you have made sure that the input parameters are in the exact order you need them you can simply ask for the elements to do stuff like `"powershell.exe $Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA" + parts[0] +" ... " + parts[...];`

Comment: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545611/executing-powershell-commands-in-java-program   <- this will help you

Comment: @px06 yes I'm sure.i should try this: "powershell.exe $Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA + parts[0]  + parts[1]" ; without " end of  $Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA" ?

Comment: @px06 I wrote ("powershell.exe $Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA + parts[0] + parts[1]")  or ("powershell.exe $Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA + 'parts[0]' + 'parts[1]' " ) but i have ioexeption

Comment: @Onkar I used this.now when i execute the powershell I want to pass my array instead of enter the value myself : String command = "powershell.exe  $Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -ZoneName -Name -IPv4Address -TimeToLive";

Comment: Combine your array as one string  by seperating comma(,) and then execute

Comment: @Onkar  "powershell.exe  Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name ' zoneName ' -ZoneFile 'zoneFileName' " zone name and zone file are in my string array and i want to put them in this script.what should i do?

Comment: Yes You can use ProcessBuilder refer   fireandfuel answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). You have to put each parameter (including path to the program) as items to an array or list and pass it to the constructor of `ProcessBuilder`.

for example:

```
String[] arguments = {"powershell.exe", "$Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA", "-ZoneName", "[your zone name]", "-Name", "[your name]", "-IPv4Address", "[your ipv4 address]", "-TimeToLive", "[your TTL]"};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(arguments);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

As an alternative you can use [Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-)