# How to determinate if 2 logical drives are on the same physical disc in Java

Tags: java, hard-drive

Imagine a PC with an SSD, and a HDD.

SSD is splitted to 2 partitions: C and D.

HDD is splitted to 2 partitions: E and F.

**I need to create a method:**

```
boolean isOnSamePhysicalDrive(String drive1, String drive2);
```

isOnSamePhysicalDrive("C", "D") --> *true*

isOnSamePhysicalDrive("E", "F") --> *true*

isOnSamePhysicalDrive("C", "E") --> *false*

Comment: I assume answers should be windows only, as you used windows hard disk names?

Comment: Yeah, it's WIndows-only

Comment: Have you tried accessing the registry in similar fashion to this solution at the second-to-bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327718/how-to-list-physical-disks ?

Comment: If you are running your programm on a system where you got powershell [this](https://superuser.com/a/1147305) could be a way to go.
In addition with [executing-powershell-commands-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545611/executing-powershell-commands-in-java-program/29545926).

Comment: Closer, but one issue: My Laptop currently has the following setup: CEF drives on SSD, DGH drives on HDD, and I on External HDD. When I run command 'powershell.exe  Get-Disk (Get-Partition -DriveLetter 'H').DiskNumber' it prints error for DGH drives. Maybe because HDD is dynamic disc?

Answer (score 3):

`Java.nio.file.FileStore` is what you are looking for.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html

> Storage for files. A FileStore represents a storage pool, device,
>   **partition**, volume, concrete file system or other implementation
>   specific means of file storage.

This code prints the names of my partitions when executed.

```
for (FileStore fs: FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + fs.name());
    System.out.println("Type: " + fs.type());
}
```

As such

```
Name: SSD
Type: NTFS
Name: Door systeem gereserveerd
Type: NTFS
Name: 
Type: NTFS
```

Note that `Door systeem gereserveerd` is a partition of my main drive, SSD. Excuse the Dutch language.

[image]

`Lokale schijf` means `Local drive`
. The disk is unnamed, which is why no name shows up in the results.

To be more specific, you can use this.

```
System.out.println(Files.getFileStore(Paths.get("C:/")).name());
System.out.println(Files.getFileStore(Paths.get("E:/")).name());
```

Will print the name of a specific drive or partition. In my case:

```
SSD
Door systeem gereserveerd
```

Comment: `FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores().forEach(fileStore -> System.out.println(fileStore.name() + " - " + fileStore.type()));` returns

Windows - NTFS
HDD Programs - NTFS
SSD Prog - NTFS
Develop - NTFS
Torrent - NTFS
Storage - NTFS
ext_storage - NTFS

For me, however these drives takes place on 3 physical drives (SSD, HDD, External HDD), and I cannot see the mapping of the physical / logical drives

Comment: It would seem that `getAttribute(String attribute)` is what we need to use. I am however unable to find documentation on `FileStore` attributes.

Comment: getAttribute support values: totalSpace, usableSpace, unallocatedSpace, volume:vsn, volume:isRemovable and volume:isCdrom for Concrete class WindowsFileStore