# Embedding a powershell script in JAX-RS / Jersey

Tags: powershell, jersey, jax-rs

I'm relatively new to the JAX-RS / Jersey and I am trying to execute a powershell script in my REST Web Service but I don't want to inline my script into my Java code. Is it possible to embed a powershell script into a Jersey Restful Web Service and read it as a stream during runtime like how it is done by embedding it as a text resource in Visual Studio project? I have tried search online but I'm able to find any reference on embedding resource in JAX-RS/Jersey

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing PowerShell Commands in Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545611/executing-powershell-commands-in-java-program)

Comment: I have read that question but its suggestion is either to inline the powershell command in the Java code or invoke the script stored in a hard code location in the file system. My question is whether it is possible to embed the script as part of the JAX-RS / Jersey Web Service like a resource file in a Visual Studio project

Comment: No. Java != .NET. BTW, this is in no way related to JAX-RS and Jersey. It is just a Java + Powershell question.