# Can i send a string variable from eclipse (java) to a powershell script

Tags: java, powershell, powershell-core

i have used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29545926/12502255) to be able to run a script through a java program to simply get a text output (it works as required).

```
  String command = "powershell.exe  \"C:\\Users\\--\\--\\script.ps1\" ";
  Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

i am looking at furthering my script within java to use said script on multiple pages, with the only change being an address variable ideally passed through from a loop within eclipse. i have `$address` variable in my script.ps1 file where it is currently declared at the top of my powershell script - ideally i want to be able to declare `$address` in eclipse.

Is this possible? or would i need to adjust the script another way.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the variable using `Runtime.exec`, but you'll have to do it in the same command, otherwise the script will lose the context, because it will run in a different powershell that does not know the variable.

So, in one command you `Set-Variable` (or `SET` for cmd, or `EXPORT` for linux) and call your `ps1` script (or in my case, `echo`):

```
String myvar = "TextTextText";

final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] commands = {"powershell.exe", "Set-Variable", "-Name \"myvar\" -Value \""+myvar+"\";", "echo $myvar"};

Process proc = rt.exec(commands);

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

String s = null;

while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: You can also modify you script to expect a command line argument and pass it while calling from java

Comment: thank you heaps! this works. big thank you - appreciate your help