# How can I call Cypress tests from inside a java tests (testng)?

Tags: cypress, rest-assured

I have a project in which I have Cypress Tests, and API Tests (Using Rest-assured). I want to call some Cypress tests from inside the Rest-assured project and continue with verifying the results in APIs. How can I do this integration?

Comment: I think, from RA project, you can call Powershell and execute some commands to run Cypress test. This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/29545926/7574461